# Defining a custom text function in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a very simply shiny app that just renders some text:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h5("This is some text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to change the styling of this text, for example, to make the text color red. I know that I can do this by creating a 'www' subfolder and adding some css in a file called 'custom':

```
.h5, h5 {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

And then reference this stylesheet in the app:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")),
  h5("This is some text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Doing this accomplishes what I want, but it overwrites the properties for the `h5` function. Is there anyway to create a duplicate `h5` function (maybe `h5_red`) and apply the css to that, so that I can retain the default properties of `h5`, but also use my new `h5_red` function throughout my app as needed?

Comment: `shiny::h5("hello", style="color:#ff0000;")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you use classes for that?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(
    HTML(
      "h5.red {color:#FF0000;}"
    )),
      
  h5("This is some text", class = 'red')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can obviously include `h5.red {color:#FF0000;}` in the css file that you have. So whenever you need red color `h5` text apply `class = 'red'` to it which will not change the overall `h5` property.